# GUI type application for Scheduling Jobs

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, jobs, job-scheduling

Is there any Python library or framework that provide scheduling of Jobs in windows having GUI. By jobs, I mean some batch files or Python scripts. 
An application where edit, create and deletion of jobs are available.

I have tried and looked a lot of questions, and finally mashed up. 
Please suggest some library or a way to create one GUI application for the same.

Comment: (1) What you're looking for likely exists, in several variants. (2) Questions like this are explicitly off-topic on this site, though: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1):

I used Tkinter and PyQt5 .What I really recommend is PyQt5 for many reasons:-
1.Easy syntx 
2.More human readable

and lastly there is an application created to ease and save time on designing the app
for PyQt5 which is Qt designer it's going to convert all the look of you application into python codes so all you have to do copy , paste and do the functionality like when clicking a button something happens etc. Highly recommend PyQt

Comment: How PyQt5 will help in scheduling tasks? can u plz help @officialAhmed?

Comment: you need to write an application using tkinter and PyQT5